# Wifi router - different bandwidth allocation for each mac addresse

Tags: wifi

Is it possible to filter wifi users by their MAC addresses and allocate different bandwidth for each of them?

Say, a device (having MAC address 14-CC-20-0A-2A-6E) will get 5mbps and another device (14-CC-20-0A-5A-12) will get 3mbps?

Is there any router that can help me achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? There may be a router that does this, but I imagine you can accomplish the same thing with built in QoS rules which are on most mid-range and better routers.